# How can I set click event for a child MenuItem without raise parent event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code :

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
    <MenuItem Header="Parent" Click="ParentItem_Click" >
        <MenuItem Header="Child" Click="ChildItem_Click">
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

When I click child MenuItem, the parent MenuItem will be raise too. I don't want that parent event raised.

Comment: provide more code - and what is it, wpf or winforms

Comment: If you are considering top level menu items then naturally you will need to click on parent then select child. So ultimately there will be top level parent menu item event raised.

Comment: hi irfan when the mouse go over the parent appear sub menu too.it dont necessary to click it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As click is routed, you may use this code

```
private void OnYourMenuItemClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
     MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
     if(null != item)
     {
         // Handle needed menu item click here
     }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

This is standard behaviour for events with Bubbling routing strategy. You can manually set `eventArgs.Handled =  true` in the event handler. See [Marking Routed Events as Handled, and Class Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747183.aspx)

Considering that `Click` event is not paired with a tunneling event like `PreviewClick` - you can try out using [PreviewMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmousedown.aspx) [PreviewMouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup.aspx) tunneling events and see whether you can attach your logic to these events.

[Routed event strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies):

> **Bubbling**: Event handlers on the event source are invoked. The routed event then routes to successive parent elements until reaching
>   the element tree root. Most routed events use the bubbling routing
>   strategy. Bubbling routed events are generally used to report input or
>   state changes from distinct controls or other UI elements.
>
> **Direct**: Only the source element itself is given the opportunity to invoke handlers in response. This is analogous to the "routing" that
>   Windows Forms uses for events. However, unlike a standard CLR event,
>   direct routed events support class handling (class handling is
>   explained in an upcoming section) and can be used by EventSetter and
>   EventTrigger.
>
> **Tunneling**: Initially, event handlers at the element tree root are invoked. The routed event then travels a route through successive
>   child elements along the route, towards the node element that is the
>   routed event source (the element that raised the routed event).
>   Tunneling routed events are often used or handled as part of the
>   compositing for a control, such that events from composite parts can
>   be deliberately suppressed or replaced by events that are specific to
>   the complete control. Input events provided in WPF often come
>   implemented as a tunneling/bubbling pair. Tunneling events are also
>   sometimes referred to as Preview events, because of a naming
>   convention that is used for the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years and a half old, but the solution was pretty easy (I just figured it out). Just give names to the items.

XAML

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
    <MenuItem x:Name="Parent" Header="Parent" Click="ParentItem_Click" >
        <MenuItem x:Name="Child" Header="Child" Click="ChildItem_Click">
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

CODE

```
private void ParentItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
     if(item == Parent)
     {
         // Handle Parent
     }
}

private void ChildItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MenuItem item = e.OriginalSource as MenuItem;
     if(item == Child)
     {
         // Handle Child
     }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!